# Looking through 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a personal project. 
I have the following data

**tbl A**

id, blah, blah

**tbl B**

id, id_2

**tbl C**

id_2, Result

I have check for the following, if id in tbl A exists in tbl B AND if Pass = 'A'.

I can write a query to check for the keys in A exists in B. 
Something like,

```
SELECT * FROM tblA as a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM tblB as b 
  WHERE a.id = b.id)
```

And this works fine.

I can also write something with an INNER JOIN

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabC 
 INNER JOIN tblB ON tblC.id2 = tblB.id2
 INNER JOIN tblA ON tblB.id = tblA.id
WHERE Result = 'A' GROUP BY id
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to combine both these queries together.

Comment: Sample data and desired results always help.  Your sample data and queries seem to have nothing to do with the condition that `PASS = 'A'`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like below

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM tabC c
 INNER JOIN tblB b ON c.id2 = b.id2
 INNER JOIN tblA a ON b.id = a.id
 WHERE Result = 'A' 
 and NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM tblB as b1 
  WHERE a.id = b1.id)
```

Comment: Thank You. I just have one question, let's say I have an ID '0002' in the ID column in tblA and I don't have the it in ID column but I have it in another column which I don't want to do anything with. How can i avoid this?

Comment: WHERE a.id = b1.id, will check for all of the columns for some reason and I am looking for a way to avoid this.

Comment: This would never return any rows. You have an inner join between tblA and tblB on id. Then the NOT EXISTS says to not return any of the rows where those two values match.